# Projective tensor product of the normad spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

How can we show that if $X$ and $Y$ are infinite-dimensional normed spaces, then the projective tensor product of $X$ and $Y$, $X\otimes_\pi Y$, is an incomplete space?

Ps: It is Exercise $2.5$ from Ryan's book (Introduction to tensor products). Unfortunately I did not resolve it.

Comment: Can you define the projective tensor product?

Comment: that formula isn't clear how

Comment: @JanielyMaria. Please use TeX when writing formulas.

Comment: @FedericoFallucca. I found [here](https://goo.gl/aV2VbF) that $X \otimes_\pi Y$ is just $X \otimes Y$ endowed with the projective norm $\pi$ defined by
$$\pi(u) = \inf \{ \sum_i \|x_i\| \|y_i\| : u= \sum_i x_i \otimes y_i \}$$

Comment: @JanielyMaria. What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of how it could be done? Do you know what *incomplete* means?